# Success callback is executing after all cordova.exec functions have ended

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am building a phonegap application and my current native platform is android. I have a problem. I have a array list built in java. And I have to compare the array with a service that i called from javascript. But issue is that when i call cordova.exec inside for loop, first entire for loop executes and then the control shifts to callbacksuccess for all cordova.exec.

My code is-

```
 $.ajax({
      url : ...,  
      type: "GET",
      data: null,
      setTimeout:1,
      dataType:"JSON",
      success: function(response)
      {
         var mydata='';
         for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
         {
           alert('inside for '+i);
            obj=response[i];
            var testpackage=obj.PackageName;
            cordova.exec(callbacks,callbacke,'MyPlugin','plugin2',[testpackage]);
         }
      },
     error: function()
     {
        alert('Failed to fetch list.Try again later.');
     }
    });
function callbacks(e)
{
alert('success');
}
```

My callbacks() function is called after the whole for loop executes.
The output that I am receiving is-

```
inside for 0
inside for 1
inside for 2
success
success
success
```

My expected output is-

```
inside for 0
success
inside for 1
success
inside for 2
success
```

I have tried many things. Still I am not finding the solution.
            Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

cordova.exec call is asynchronous. Therefore you should change your code such that you call the consecutive cordova.execs inside the callback itself or implement something similar; simply wait for each exec call to complete before calling the next one.

Comment: Can I do something that I can get array of data from java code to javascript at my callback? I am not able to send data from java code to javascript. Please help

Comment: @megha just read cordova documentation on writing plugins. You have more info there than you need.

Comment: I have read that entirely and in depth. But it says nothing about passing array of results to callback function from java code back to javascript